# Local caching of API Gateway calls by an iOS app

Tags: ios, caching, aws-api-gateway

Does AWS API Gateway offer response caching for iOS apps?
If so, what's the approach for implementing it?

I know APIG implements server-side caching but I'd like local caching too.

I've found in AWS Core, tumblr/TMCache - separate from APIG but I guess intended to be used to wrap calls to APIG with.

I've also found https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache, an improved caching solution.

But before I start off an reinvent another cache-wrapper does AWS APIG offer anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway service offers only server-side caching as of now. For client side caching, you will need to use some other solution.